# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(a \cdot \operatorname{sinc}(w \cdot \frac{a}2))^2}{\lvert w\rvert} dw $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am desperately trying to find a solution for the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(a \cdot \operatorname{sinc}(w \cdot \frac{a}2))^2}{\lvert w\rvert} dw $$

I have already used the Wolfram Alpha Calculator and tried to find any paper regarding that topic, unfortunately without success.

This integral is used to determine the variance of the phase difference between a signal and a delayed version of it. A solution for that integral is particularly needed in order to calculate the Power Spectral Density of 1/f-Phase noise and simulate it via Matlab.

I hope you can help me finding a solution for that expression.

Thank you in advance and cheers!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137918/discussion-on-question-by-jeanclaude-evaluating-int-infty-infty-fraca).